# What does the character `,` does here?

Tags: c++

I accidentally compile a code that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Thing {
    Thing(const int a) : a(a) {};
    int a = -1;
    void set_a(const int a) { this->a = a; };
};

void strange(Thing& t) {
    t.set_a(-1), 2, t.set_a(3); // <-- ?
}

int main() {
    Thing t(3);
    strange(t);
    std::cout << t.a; //output 3
    return 0;
}
```

But why does it compile in the first place ?
What does `,` mean in the declaration of the function `strange` ?

[Run it live here](https://ideone.com/6mqCOI)

Comment: _in the declaration of the function_ you mean definition?

Comment: @manni66 Without previous declaration, a definition of a function declare it at the same time. So, this could be valid in this context ;)

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious, I don't understand why this is flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19198977/487892 instead of the accepted one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't scrolled enough. There should be a functionality like `Community accepted answer`.